# Convergence of eigenvalues $\lambda_{i}^k$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image: weevil question]

I've been trying to solve this for a while now but can't seem to figure it out. My initial intuition is to just calculate the limit of $\lambda_{2}^k$ using [de Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) like so:

$\lim_{k\to \infty} \lambda_{2}^k\big(\cos(k\phi) + i\sin(k\phi)\big)$

But I don't exactly know how to evaluate such limits at all and even then, clearly, this is not the expected approach.

I also thought about calculating the fixed point of A for the eigenvalues

$Null(\lambda_{2} I-A)$ and $Null(\lambda_{3} I-A)$

But given that $\lambda_{2}$ and $\lambda_{3}$ are complex numbers, the row reduction process just became complicated. Is this a correct approach? If so, is there a simpler way of solving this question?

Comment: You are overly complicating things, notice that $|\lambda_j^k|=|\lambda_j|^k$ and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit of $z^n$ as $n\to\infty$ is either $0,1,\infty$ or not defined! Can you see which one this is?

In particular, the fact that $|z^n|=|z|^n$ (which is clear from de Moivre, if you like, with the correct $|\cdot|$ signs) means that you only need to look at $|z|$ to find which is possible.

Comment: The limit of $z^n$ as $n \to \infty = \infty$ so I suppose the eigenvalues convergence to $\infty$? I considered this but when the question asked about the convergence I thought it was going to be something other than $\infty$, thus, the confusion in my part.

Comment: Nope, that's not true for all $z$, which is why I gave the three possible options. What is $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$ for large $n$?

Comment: Oops. In the general case, the limit is undefined unless we know or have range for the value of z. But since $|\lambda_{2}| = |\lambda_{3}| = 0.6$ we know that $0.6^n$ for large $n$ converges to 0.

Comment: You're right that $|\lambda_2| < 1$ implies the limit is zero, yes! However, in my example $2^{-n} \to 0$ also, for exactly the same reason, so I think you might need to think a bit about what these limits mean.

Comment: Ah, thanks for your help, I think I'm setup properly now to answer the rest of the questions.